# In the past, did Goblin Slayer rescue Sword Maiden?

Tags: goblin-slayer

As you see below this picture, it was on chapter 29 where Goblin Slayer and Sword Maiden meet to together and then the Sword Maiden seems like have a flashback and see Goblin Slayer as below this picture. (A helmet with a horn.)

[image]

And I found that the first equipment that Goblin Slayer equip also have a similar like that above picture. (*Have the horn.) Here's the first equipment that Goblin Slayer wearing.

[image]

So in the old time when sword maiden get humiliate by the goblins, did Goblin Slayer save the Sword Maiden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goblin Slayer has been an active adventurer for 5 years at the beginning of the story. Sword Maiden defeated the Demon Lord with the Heroes and became gold-rank 10 years prior to the events of vol. 2. So, for Sword Maiden to be captured and then saved by Goblin Slayer, it would have happened way after she's famous as a gold-rank adventurer. I don't think it's been explicitly revealed WHEN was she captured, but I find it hard to believe it happened after defeating the Demon Lord, so the one who saved her was probably not Goblin Slayer.

Comment: I think this makes sense, unless, of course, she was not saved but escaped. I recall the wikia mentioning she escaped but there were no citations so I'm not sure where that info comes from. This would then add a question as to what the flashback means...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, the timeline doesn't quite match up. Given how Sword Maiden can still see but everything is fuzzy to her, this image could be the way she perceives Goblin Slayer. Note how he looks much more heroic, his armor is cleaner and more in line with the classic Knight in Shining Armor.